# Best method to store a large number of constants C#

Tags: c#, xml, datatable, constants

Fairly new to c#, I have a datatable with 250 rows, one of the columns will be populated with constant values (these values are strings). What is the best way to store these constants? Any reference links to your suggestions would be greatly appreciated. One method I was thinking was using an xml file but I am unsure how easy it would then be to add values to the datatable.

Comment: Where do those strings come from. Do you have it in a given format already ? Are they going to be generated ? In one word, can you specify the prerequisites ?

Comment: they are predefined, ie each row will have its own unique string that is defined before start up

Comment: You mean method to store it in database or in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you want to store from a file to a database...

C# XML support is fine :

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
```

Then assuming you have this kind of XML structure :

```
<Db>
    <Item str_attr="ghjgjg" other_attr="0" .../>
    <Item str_attr="fsfsff" other_attr="1" .../>
    ...
</Db>
```

Then you can browse it as follows :

```
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("db.xml");
while (textReader.Read())
{
    String str = textReader.GetAttribute("str_attr");
    if (str != null) { // The current item has an attribute named "str_attr"
        // Code to insert 'str' to db here
   }
}
```

This is pretty straight forward.

Possible code to populate the database :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(...);
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO my_table (my_str_field) " + "VALUES (@str)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@str", str);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: for some reason it wouldn't let me use the code textReader.HasAttribute("str_attr") so i did it a slightly different way

Answer (score 2):

So what I ended up doing is the following:

I Created an xml with the following format

```
<Db>
    <identify>
        <row>
            <column2>Name</column2>
            <column3></column3>
        </row>
          :
          :
          :
     </identify>
</Db>
```

Then to read the information from the xml file I used the following code:

```
XmlTextReader textReader = new XmlTextReader("db.xml");
textReader.ReadStartElement("Db");
string column2="";
for (int row = 0; row < NumOfRows; row++)
{
    if (row == 0)
    {
        textReader.ReadStartElement("identify");
    }

    textReader.ReadStartElement("row");
    column2 = textReader.ReadElementString("column2");
    dataView[row][2] = column2;
    dataView[row][3] = textReader.ReadElementString("column3");
    textReader.ReadEndElement(); //row
}
```

Note: I am using the information stored in the xml and placing it into a datatable.

Comment: Glad to here that. Cheers !